# node server running on port 80 but cant call it by domain

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, server

I finally got my Angular5 server running. But when I start it on port 80 I can't call it by [domain].de or https://[domain].de; only https://[domain].de:80 works. 
Why is that so?

I start the server by this command:

```
 ng serve --host [domain].de --port 80 --disable-host-check -ssl true --ssl-cert "/etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain].de/cert.pem" -ssl-key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain].de/privkey.pem"
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have SSL specified as true but also port 80. By default, browsers expect `https` to be on port 443 and for port 80 to be unencrypted.

If you just specify the hostname and not the scheme, the browser assumes you want an unencrypted connection on port 80. But your port 80 is encrypted. So it fails.

If you specify `https` as the scheme but don't specify a port number, the browser assumes you want to connect on port 443. But you are running on port 80 instead. So the connection fails.

So your URLs only work in browsers if you specify both the port number and `https` as the scheme.

If you don't want to have to specify the port number, the best thing to do is probably to use port 443. If you still want to answer on port 80, set something up there to redirect the `https` scheme.

Comment: Thanks https://[domain].de now works fine. But just [domain].de doesnt. How do I fix that?